# Symfony2 Login - Bad Credentials

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I've been trying to get a database login system working with Symfony2. I've read through the docs but I'm totally stumped now as to what to do...

Every time I try to log in I just get 'Bad Credentials'.

The 'User' class implementing UserInterface is here:

http://pastebin.com/9uzbwM9v

The 'UserRepository' class is here:

http://pastebin.com/Gn0AbZb4

The 'security.yml' file is here:

http://pastebin.com/50FUNnbq

The database scheme is like this:

http://pastebin.com/5nj0rXhs

I just have no idea where to go from here... :L I've been looking around and I'm just not getting some of the other things in tutorials, maybe it's just the time of day! It's been a long week...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you also dump your profiler log?

Comment: This one?

http://pastebin.com/AHP2vMfq . I'll tell you this too, I checked the MySQL general log to see the actual query and that does bring back the correct row in the database.

Comment: Then that means the password must be incorrect. How was the SHA1 password encrypted when you inserted it into your database?

Comment: What's wrong with pasting code right here instead of pastebin?

Comment: I figured it'd save some space on here, especially in the comments, there's not real issue with it at all.

The password was just run through SHA1, once, by itself, without a salt.

Comment: Alright, I've managed to get logged in now. That's all great. Even the roles work now too. The problem was that I had a salt specified in the database, but hadn't encrypted the password with the salt...

The thing with it is, I don't know how Symfony2 encrypts passwords with a salt, but this shouldn't be an issue as I'm going to be using an external encryption library for it anyway and won't need the salt field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, you have a small typo in your `loadUserByUsername` method:

```
->where('u.account_name = :usefdgdfgfrname OR u.account_email = :email')
```

Should be:

```
->where('u.account_name = :username OR u.account_email = :email')
```

Comment: Haha, yeah, I realized I put that there after, but that wasn't it. +1 though for the spot.